# I do not understand this temp variable usage for reversing an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
/ Iterative java program to reverse an
// array
public class GFG {
      
   /* Function to reverse arr[] from 
    start to end*/
    static void rvereseArray(int arr[],
                    int start, int end)
    {
        int temp;
           
        while (start < end)
        {
            temp = arr[start]; 
            arr[start] = arr[end];
            arr[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        } 
    }     
       
    /* Utility that prints out an
    array on a line */
    static void printArray(int arr[], 
                            int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
           
         System.out.println();
    } 
  
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[]) {
          
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        printArray(arr, 6);
        rvereseArray(arr, 0, 5);
        System.out.print("Reversed array is \n");
        printArray(arr, 6); 
         
    }
}
  
// This code is contributed by Sam007
```

```
temp = arr[start]; 
            arr[start] = arr[end];
            arr[end] = temp;
```

I see this pattern a lot, but I never understand it.

How can you just say arr[start] is arr[end]? Wouldn't that just make it be the same thing?

I just don't get this pattern at all.

While start < end

so the beginning of the array is less (why does this matter because literally in reversing an arary it doesn't matter about that?)

2,7,6,9

9,6,7,2

or is it referring to the index and not the value of the int within the array?

Comment: `start` and `end` are _positions_ in the array, not their values. So while the starting position is less than the ending position, switch the two values there, then move "inward" (one further from the end, and one further from the start). You need `temp` to store the value you overwrite the first time you set a value -- you can only write one at a time, and if you don't keep what you overwrote, you won't know what to write into the other location after.

Comment: With respect, the issues you raise are fundamental to programming: the meaning of assignment, what a variable is, and the concept of arrays. Example: "How can you just say arr[start] is arr[end]" -- but no-one is saying that; the code says "assign the current value of the end'th array element to the start'th array element".  It's an **action**.

Comment: Let's put aside the array. Suppose your had two variables `int a, b;`  In your program, you determine the values need to be swapped. What code would you write to swap the values?

Comment: "How can you just say arr[start] is arr[end]? Wouldn't that just make it be the same thing?" That's correct. After that line, both values at position start and end do in fact have the same value! That's why they first stored the value at position start in the temp variable, so that value would not be lost. To swap the values at positions start and stop: (1) Store the value at position start in temp, (2) Set the value at position start to the value at position end, (3) Set the value at position end to temp. The temp var allows you to complete the swap and not have both values the same.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Let's say int a = 5 and int b = 10... I would just say int b = a and int a = b.. I think I get it now this way.. So you want me to use a temp variable.. For example, int a = temp int a = int b, temp = int b... now a is b, and b is a? correct?

Comment: Including the `int` at this point is wrong. `int a` creates a new variable. Since `a` and `b` already have values, they already exist. Depending on the context, `int a` will either result in a compiler error or create a new variable that "hides" the previous variable.

Comment: Try this: ... int a = 247; int b = 25; System.out.println ("a is " + a + ".  b is " + b + "."); a = b; b = a; ... Next, use a debugger. Set a breakpoint on the System.out. ... line. Run the code step-by-step while monitoring the values of a and of b. Do you find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

(In case a visual description is easier than the answer in the comments)

Like the comment says, `start` and `end` are positions in the array.

Starting at the extremities of the array:
`start=0`  `end=array.length`
| **x** | | | | | | | | | | **x** |

Swap the values at those locations

```java
int temp = arr[start];     // put the value at start into a temp variable.
arr[start] = arr[end];     // put the value at end into the start location.
arr[end] = temp;           // put the value you stored in temp (what used to
                           // be in start) into the current end location.
```

..then you add 1 to start and subtract one from end:
`start=1` `end=array.length-1`
| | **x** | | | | | | | | **x** | |

...and repeat the process as long as `start` < `end` (they won't cross)